# one id for more than one widget android

Tags: android

Is there any way to refer more than one widget (ui controls) by a single id
For example
i have many `ImageView` with same  `android:id="myimageview"`
And in my activity

```
 myimageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimageview);
```

So if i set an image using

```
myimageview.setImageBitmap(somebitmap);
```

i need that image in all of my Imageview with id myimageview
But when i tried this only one of imageview got this change.
Any idea to do this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.

At least I did not see a API method in the documentation yet. ID is UNIQUE (stands for **identifier**). You can use a **TAG** (`android:tag` in your XML file) and then get the parent View.

Then, you might want to try an function like [getTouchables()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTouchables%28%29) on your parent view and use all the views that match when calling [getTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28%29).